# Can Magit do git format-patch?

Tags: magit

I just wanted to know if Magit has this functionality. The reference [manual](https://magit.github.io/magit.html) does not have this explicitly so that's why I am asking.

Comment: @itsjeyd yes, sorry, I was trying out sx.el (the stackexchange client for emacs) and it didn't show any answers. Once I opened the link in a browser I saw it, sorry :( [EDIT]: deleted comment

Comment: @LeeH No problem, thanks for following up! :)

Comment: @LeeH That's very odd. If you run into that problem again please file a bug report.

Comment: @Malabarba I did! Then it was fixed in sx.el and everything works now :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're right, it doesn't seem to be built in. But note that you can run *any* `git` subcommand you like from a Magit buffer by pressing <kbd>:</kbd>, which is bound to `magit-git-command` by default:

> `magit-git-command` is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function
>   in `magit.el`.
>
> `(magit-git-command ARGS DIRECTORY)`
>
> Execute a Git subcommand asynchronously, displaying the output.
>   With a prefix argument run Git in the root of the current
>   repository.  Non-interactively run Git in `DIRECTORY` with `ARGS`.

So in order to get a patch for, e.g., the latest commit using `git format-patch` you can do the following:

<kbd>:</kbd> `format-patch -1` <kbd>RET</kbd>

The output (displayed in the `*magit-process*` buffer) will look something like this:

```
  0 git --no-pager -c core.preloadindex=true format-patch -1
0001-Commit-message-associated-with-latest-commit.patch
```

Answer (score 18):

Starting with `v2.1.0` Magit provides basic support for `git format-patch` as well as `git request-pull`. They share a popup, `magit-patch-popup`, which <kbd>W</kbd> is bound to.